# Are there prepositions that cannot be replaced by "je"?

Tags: prepositions

I have often heard that you can use *je* when doubting which preposition to use. Is this always the case?

Answer (score 12):

*Je* is not intended for occasions of doubt, but rather when a preposition is needed but none of the defined prepositions are suitable. In practice, *je* is used infrequently, and most often in set phrases.

- Time espressions (*je la tria horo*)
- *je via sano*
- *je la barbo de Zamenhof!*
- *plena je io* (although *plena **de** io* is more common.)
- *graveda je knabo*
- *mi kredas je Dio*